# Programmatically get pages which are created using custom page layout

Tags: caml-query, pages

I have custom ArticlePage.aspx page layout.

I have created some pages in Pages library using ArticlePage layout.

Now programmatically. I'm trying to get that pages with their properties.

I did some code but it's not working.

Please suggest some code.

Comment: Show us what you have done so far.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to find the pages which are using "ArticlePage" layout. **SPSiteDataQuery** is used for cross site query, so all pages site collection or specific web can be retrieved.

```
SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Site.RootWeb;
SPSiteDataQuery query = new SPSiteDataQuery();

//Server template for pages library is 850
query.Lists = "<Lists ServerTemplate='850' Hidden='TRUE' />";  

query.ViewFields = @"<FieldRef Name='URL' Nullable='True' Type='URL' /><FieldRef Name='Title' Nullable='TRUE' Type='Text' />";

query.Webs = "<Webs Scope='Recursive'  />";
query.Query = @"<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ContentType'/><Value Type='Text'>ArticlePage</Value></Eq></Where>"
DataTable dt = web.GetSiteData(query);
```

Hope this might be helpful.